# Как может выглядеть иконка "Бесплатно" в размере 32px?

Tags: иконки, дизайн

Как бы вы нарисовали иконку "free"? Гугл по запросу "free icon", выдаёт кучу бесплатных иконок, вместо самого изображения бесплатности.

Comment: Попробуй поискать [здесь](http://www.iconsearch.ru/). Там очень много иконок

Comment: По запросу `free` только одна иконка. 

Попробуйте лучше http://findicons.com

Answer (score 7):

Вот два примера:

[image]
[image]

(источник: png.findicons.com)